# Git move single commit from feature_branch to master

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase, cherry-pick

What is the simplest way to achieve this?

from:

```
--A--B         
      \
       1--2--3
```

to:

```
--A--B--2
         \
          1--3
```

I can't figure any simple way to achieve this (less than like 5 steps).

Comment: The result does not respect the order anymore? Are you sure you didn't made a mistake?

Comment: Changeset `1` was added after `B`, how is it supposed to become after `2` on the second graph? What is the real task?

Comment: Thats it. I need to pick the "middle commit" from my feature branch and put it somehow to the master and rebase.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You left out the labels; let's put them back in.  Here's "before":

```
--A--B          <-- master
      \
       1--2--3  <-- feature
```

and here is "after".  I will mark these with a tick mark (or "prime" or whatever you like to call it) as they will be copies of the original commits, with new and different commit-IDs.

```
--A--B--2'      <-- master
         \
          1'-3' <-- feature
```

This cannot be done in a single step: it takes at least two.

First we have to re-order the `1--2--3` sequence so that `2` comes first.  The easiest way is probably an interactive rebase (while on branch `feature`, using the git command `git rebase -i master`): just change the `pick` order and rebase will cherry-pick 2, then 1, then 3 and move the `feature` label:

```
--A--B          <-- master
      \
       2'-1'-3' <-- feature
```

Now we need only move the `master` label to point to commit `2'`.  Many commands will do this, but the simplest is `git merge` instructed to do a fast-forward merge (to avoid errors):

```
git checkout master; git merge --ff-only feature~2
```

To avoid checking out `master` we can use `git branch -f` as in [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21232760/1256452) (which appeared while I was editing this one), e.g.:

```
git branch -f master feature~2
```

(in both cases we need to name commit `2'`; with `git branch` we must name the branch to move, while with `git merge` we have to be *on* the branch to be moved).

---

Just for completeness, here's a different but equivalent method (using four git commands).  First let's get on branch `master`:

```
git checkout master
```

Now we can cherry-pick commit `2`, creating a copy, `2'`:

```
git cherry-pick feature^     # or feature~1
```

which produces this graph:

```
--A--B--2'      <-- master
      \
       1--2--3  <-- feature
```

Now we can rebase `feature` interactively onto the new `master`, dropping commit `2`:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase -i master
```

Change the `pick` lines to copy 1 and 3 and omit 2, as commit `2'` is already there on `master`.

Comment: Nicely done, well detailed, much more so than in my own answer. +1

Answer (score 4):

Mainly:

```
--A--B         (master)
      \
       1--2--3 (B)



git checkout B
git rebase -i master # reorder commits

--A--B         (master)
      \
       2--1--3 (B)

git branch -f master 2
```

Comment: This is as elegant as I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you can get the commit hash from

```
 git reflog
```

then go to master branch.

```
git checkout master
```

then cherry pick the relevent commit

```
git cherry-pick <commit-hash>
```

The commit will applied to master branch if there are no conflicts.